# Check All checkbox function inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, modal-dialog

If user clicks 'add data' a modal opens, I have individual checkboxes for data1,data2,data3,data4. I also have a check all checkbox. If user clicks this, it should be able to select all above 4, if clicks again, it should deselect all. Also, once selected, the value of 'Select All' should change to 'Deselect All'

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

        <div class="modal-body">
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1"> Data1</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"> Data2</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value3"> Data3</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value4"> Data4</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value5">Select All</label><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Add data</button>
</div>
```

Can someone let me know how to achieve this. I saw a lot of posts online but each had ng-repeat for the first 4 checkboxes. Mine is without using ng-repeat. Can someone please advise.

I have the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nSCGJzj1zG5SGO2N76L3?p=preview

Comment: your plunker is missing the example.js file

Comment: updated plunker in the description. here it is -- http://plnkr.co/edit/nSCGJzj1zG5SGO2N76L3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you were not binding to the items array. I fixed that by using the following markup:

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected">{{item.name}}</label>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()">Select All</label>
    <br/>
```

After that, I had to change the structure of the items property to become an object for later binding:

```
$scope.items = [{
name: 'item 1'
}, {
name: 'item 2'
}, {
name: 'item 3'
}, ];
```

To be able to update all the other checkboxes, I resorted to the following code:

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {

if ($scope.selectedAll) {
  $scope.selectedAll = true;
} else {
  $scope.selectedAll = false;
}
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
  item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
});

}
```

Please, refer to this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKU6SsocP7AGKlTsg83J?p=preview) example for the full working solution.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the example here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked#!
basically the trick is to add to all "slave" check boxes

```
ng-checked="checkboxModel.value5"
```

Comment: i thought of using ng-checked. but i wont be able to give ng-model to individual first four checkboxes. the document says ng-checked and ng-model cant be used together as it gives different behaviour and errors

Comment: You can also bind the 'select All' checkbox to some function by adding ng-change="change()" and in that function set to 'true' all other models.
( If you don't want to be aware in the JS about the list of check boxes you can also try ng-change="checkboxModel.value4=checkboxModel.value3=checkboxModel.value2=checkboxModel.value1=true")

Comment: see my plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/dDJhuxFLAyi7CCbKs1aE?p=preview

Comment: is there a way to update the text 'Select All'. so if users select all, it should show 'deselect all' and vice versa on each click

Answer (score 1):

Well, first the explanation:

1. To select/deselect all the `checkboxes`, you can simply loop over the elements and setting all the checkbox to `true/false`.
2. To select/deselect this checkbox programatically, you can use [**`Array.prototype.every()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method, which returns if all checkboxes are selected or not, if all elements are selected that option will be/keep also selected, otherwise, it will be/keep deselected.
3. To get all the selected items when you close the modal you could use the [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to return only the selected checkboxes.

Here's a *snippet* **working**:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module('ui.bootstrap.demo', [
      'ngAnimate',
      'ui.bootstrap'
    ])
    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl)
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl);

  function ModalDemoCtrl($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function(size) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          items: function() {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItems) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItems;
      }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ', new Date());
      });
    }

    $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
      $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
    }
  }

  // Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
  // It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

  function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = [];

    function loadData() {
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        arr.push({
          "name": "Item " + i
        });
      }
      return arr;
    }

    $scope.items = loadData();

    $scope.check = function() {
      $scope.selectedAll = $scope.items.every(function(value) {
        return value.Selected;
      });
    }

    $scope.selectAll = function() {
      $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
      });
    }

    function getChecked() {
      return $scope.items.filter(function(value) {
        return value.Selected;
      });
    }

    $scope.ok = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close(getChecked());
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.main_div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.0.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" ng-change="check()"> {{item.name}}
        </label>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="selectAll()"> Select All
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Add data!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to see it in plunker, click [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/co4QNSu7e6c1MyKxGABW?p=preview).

I hope it helps!!